# Inequality needed for a problem.

Tags: inequality

I tried to prove an inequality and have reduced it to this form:

> $$\sqrt{\frac{a}{b}} + \sqrt{\frac{c}{d}} \ge \sqrt\frac{a-c}{b-d},
> \quad a \ge c > 0,  b> d > 0.
> $$

I want to know if this one is true. I have no idea of proving it rather than calculations which are hard to handle.

Sorry for the non-latex format.
I am writing from my phone.

Answer (score 2):

It's obviously false. You just have to pick $b$ very close to $d$. Then the right hand side goes to infinity.

A concrete counterexample is $(a,b,c,d)=\left(3,\dfrac{11}{10},2,1\right)$.

Answer (score 2):

Counter example:
\begin{eqnarray*}
\sqrt{\frac{100}{10}} + \sqrt{\frac{1}{9}} < \sqrt{\frac{99}{1}} .
\end{eqnarray*}